# Custom UITableViewCell on Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I need to create a custom UITableViewCell,
I have created a class inside of a ViewController class.

I have written the code below;

```
class FavoritesCell: UITableViewCell
{

var timeLabel:UILabel?

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {

super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

timeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(250, 10, 70, 20))
//how to add this time label as a subview of FavoritesCell

}
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }
}
```

As i mentioned in commented line, how to add timeLabel to UITableViewCell?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've created your `timeLabel`, this should do it:

```
self.contentView.addSubview(timeLabel!)
```

This adds the `timeLabel` to the cell's `contentView` rather than the cell itself, but that's generally what you do in table view cells.

Other things to note:

- It's fine to use `self` here - after your `super.init` call, the object is fully initialised.
- You've just created the `timeLabel`, so it's safe to force-unwrap it in `addSubview`.

Comment: but this class inside another class, does it take the self as the FavoritesCell class?

Comment: Yes, @erdemgc, self in this context refers to the FavouritesCell instance. Does it not work?

Comment: what about initialising the cell inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Have you registered the cell class + identifier with the table view? If so then it's `let favouritesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TheIdentifierYouUsed", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyViewController.FavoritesCell` to get an instance of `FavouritesCell` in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

As UITableViewCell class is derived from the UIView, so you can use the same method -         self.addSubview(timeLabel!).